# Replicating hashing C# algorithm within PHP

Tags: c#, php

somebody provided me a C# code as an example for a password digest generation and I'm trying to replicate that log within PHP code.

C# script:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main(){
        var password = "1234";
        var fecha = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")));

        var nonceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(nonce);
        var createdBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fecha.ToString());
        var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        var digestBytes = new byte[nonceBytes.Length + createdBytes.Length + passwordBytes.Length];
        Array.Copy(nonceBytes, digestBytes, nonceBytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(createdBytes, 0, digestBytes, nonceBytes.Length, createdBytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(passwordBytes, 0, digestBytes, nonceBytes.Length + createdBytes.Length, passwordBytes.Length);

        var computeBytes = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(digestBytes);
        var digest = Convert.ToBase64String(computeBytes);

        Console.WriteLine(digest);
        Console.WriteLine(nonce);
        Console.WriteLine(fecha);
    }
}
```

C# dump example:

```
tM/7oLWxtQL9+eeRAxWrVEOO+Bc=
ZjA5MGM4NmJlYWZlNGVjZjllYWM1YTU4ZjA3M2YyOGY=
1/17/2020 4:45:38 PM
```

My PHP code so far:

```
<?php

function gen_nonce($length = 24)
{
    return base64_encode(random_bytes($length));
    // return base64_encode(uniqid());
}

function gen_date()
{
    return gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
}

function get_bytes($value)
{
    $sha1 = sha1($value, true);
    $encoded = base64_encode($sha1);

    return $encoded;
}

function new_bytes($value)
{
    return random_bytes(strlen($value));
}

$nonce = gen_nonce();
$date = gen_date();
$password = "1234";

// $nonce_bytes = base64_decode($nonce);
// $date_bytes = get_bytes($date);
// $password_bytes = get_bytes($password);

$digest_bytes = new_bytes($nonce.$date.$password);

$digest = base64_encode(sha1($digest_bytes, true));

$result = [
    "username" => "USERNAME",
    "password" => $digest,
    "nonce" => $nonce,
    "created" => $date,
];

echo(json_encode($result));
```

PHP dump example:

```
{"username":"USERNAME","password":"cw0LXT5Zk2\/fdU0svabD6NRobGU=","nonce":"7KQUXajiJKwUxpWATohI0GyhCLfEnUFx","created":"2020-01-17T16:59:09Z"}
```

I'm guessing my code is plain wrong cause the API that uses this password as an Authentication method is throwing a wrong credentials error message.

What can I do in order to replicate as good as possible that C# code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate where you think you went wrong? Also, maybe it would be a good idea to put the algorithm into multiple steps and verify with your PHP code all those individual steps to understand where you are drifting apart.

Comment: Well, the API won't log me in throwing the wrong credentials message. That would be it so... I think that I am generating those fields in the wrong way. I would check both codes step by step but I know nothing at all about C#, that's my problem.

Comment: As you can see in your own code with `Console.WriteLine(something);` you can simply output stuff to the console so you can use that for debugging purposes